# When is the appCheck.onTokenChanged callback invoked?

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-check

I am using appcheck in my web project and setting it up like so:

```
const appCheck = firebase.appCheck();
appCheck.activate( "my site key", true);
appCheck.onTokenChanged((token) => {
   console.log("Token:", token);
});
```

Am I correct to assume that if the onTokenChanged callback is invoked then the browser has passed appcheck attestation?

If this is so then my intention is that I would enable analytics when the callback is invoked as I can be reasonably sure that it is a legitimate user not a bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `onTokenChanged` your callback will be:

- If the App Check token already exists, your callback is invoked immediately with that value.
- If the App Check token doesn't exist yet, your callback will be invoked once it *is* generated.

In addition:

- Your callback will always be invoked when the App Check token is updated.

In any of these cases, the app has passed the checks by the attestation provider.

Answer (score 0):

Natively, this is handled like other onEvent listeners within Firebase and will return the value on success. This includes AppCheck and you can assume that the instance is authentic when it has passed App Check.